# OS library Python - Localizando Diretórios

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo como localizar diretórios em Python e me deparei com o seguite código:

```
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path)

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
```

Por que na **linguagem Python** usa-se `__file__` para se referir ao arquivo atual?

Como esse comando se relaciona com toda a sintaxe?

Qual a desvantagem em usar `os.getcwd()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só obteve o mesmo retorno nos dois casos porque está executando o script diretamente, no mesmo diretório de trabalho.

Faça o teste você mesmo, coloque esse script em algum outro diretório. Abra um prompt no desktop e execute o script a partir desse local de trabalho, por exemplo:

```
py C:\meus-scripts\script-do-arduin.py
```

A saída será:

```
C:\meus-scripts
C:\Users\Arduin\Desktop
```

Ou seja, não é a mesma coisa.

[`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) retorna uma string representando o diretório de trabalho atual, por isso deve-se tomar um certo cuidado ao utilizar [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir). Já [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) contém o *path* do arquivo no qual o módulo foi carregado (se este for carregado a partir de um arquivo).

Answer (score 0):

a expressão **file** é uma variável "mágica" que retorna uma string contendo o nome do arquivo atual.

as expressões da linha 3 e 6 são apenas formas diferentes de resolver o mesmo problema, a desvantagem da linha 3 é que você está executando 2 métodos e na linha 6 somente 1.

Comment: Não são a mesma coisa.